# Is there any change in Ubuntu 14.04 regarding parent process to Orphan process?

Tags: 14.04, bash

Actually According to my knowledge an Orphan process means a process with parent process terminated first than child process.
In this case actually the Init process takes the parent position.

But the problem is the child process PPID is not 1 init   (as 1 is Init process) in my system using Ubuntu 14.04.

in my system it is showing 4617 init --user isted of 1 init

But in 12.04 version it is showing as 1.

what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my Ubuntu 14.04.5, I see two processes called `init`, and investigatining with `ps -fp` I see:

```
w3@aardvark:~(0)$ pgrep init
1
9511
w3@aardvark:~(0)$ ps -fp1,9511
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  0 Aug09 ?        00:00:04 /sbin/init
w3        9511  9494  0 Aug09 ?        00:00:07 init --user
# follow the PPIDs back (omitted for brevity), end up with
w3@aardvark:~(0)$ ps -fp1,9511,9494,1770,1553
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  0 Aug09 ?        00:00:04 /sbin/init
root      1553     1  0 Aug09 ?        00:00:00 gdm
root      1770  1553  0 Aug09 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/gdm/gdm-simple-slave --display-id /org/gnome/DisplayManager/Displays/_0
root      9494  1770  0 Aug09 ?        00:00:00 gdm-session-worker [pam/gdm-password]
w3        9511  9494  0 Aug09 ?        00:00:07 init --user
```

So, there are two `init`s.
One, process 1, is `/sbin/init` and "owns" processes whose parent processes have exited (somebody must receive the exit status, after all), as has been traditional since the beginning of time.

The other (9511 on my system), is part of my graphical login, and is just called "init".

I'm sure you'll find the same sort of thing if you do the same investigation.